# How can a being that can create electric attacks use targeted lightning storm strikes?

Tags: physics, super-powers, lightning

I found one question that deals with how to make lightning from clouds strike a target person,
[Can we make lightning strike a certain person?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/82043/can-we-make-lightning-strike-a-certain-person) but I am looking for something that doesn't involve technology as the story is super powers science-based, there is an answer that suggests using a laser to create an ionized air path for the lighting to travel down but other than having person X stand next to person Y (the target) fire the laser up and take the strike along with the target I am not sure how to incorporate this.

I do like the idea of using lasers and a strong charge as a form of attack from the being that can generate electricity within their body, this question has answers for a gun using a double laser that I like [Lightning Rifle](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/22347/lightning-rifle).

In my other questions I have covered my beings having the ability to create electricity, I have them using it as a form of attack in many different ways but I am not sure how to have them harness the power of lightning from the clouds to strike their target.

I will save how they create a storm in a short amount of time for another question but for the time being given the fact they can create their own electromagnetic field and create fairly strong electric attacks how can they use this power to make a someone a target for repeated lightning strikes?

Comment: Isn't this problem resolved by the premise? If you have people able to deliver electric attacks from themselves, and can do it reliably and at range, then they should be able to direct *any* lightning. They have the means to control where electricity spreads. They just need to to the same but not link it to themselves (or be sure they'd survive).

Comment: @VLAZ how would they direct it? they can fire a laser from their hand to send their own electricity along, unless I am missing something I still don't see how they could use that to make someone else take the lightning strike?

Comment: Can a person with electricity superpowers use lightning from afar against somebody else? If so, *they are already directing electric discharge*. If I wave a plugged in power cord around, nobody would be electrocuted unless they are basically touching the cord. Producing reliable electric bursts at any distance means they have *some* mechanism of making electricity jump to a target. I don't know what it is but lightning is the *same thing*. It just doesn't originate from themselves. Controlling one means they can control the other.

Comment: @Vlaz I think I see what your saying but it seems like a big leap in power control, the characters are basically souped up electric eels, so trying to use that ability to make people take a strike using charge or some other method.

Comment: well they aren't eels they are human but that kind of ability taken to lasers etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to direct lightening and you don't want to use technology then how about using something like fine damp sticky but very strong spiders silk strands? Spray it on the enemy and then blow the other end up into the air to be caught on the breeze. Whilst the target is trying to disentangle itself from the sticky strands the other end will be floating up in the air and at some point will attract lightening that will discharge down the thread ionizing it as it goes and discharge through the target.

Comment: Interesting idea thanks, I do have characters that can fire sticky substances, would there be a specific sticky substance that would be best for the task?

Comment: spider silk might work. it can be very strong, light and sticky. For your purposes it could be in any thickness you want. Whatever uses it doesn't have to be a spider, it just needs to have the spider silk gland and associated biochemistry

Comment: how would you imagine it would look, for example the string that the bolt has travelled through gets fried or it stays intact for more bolt strikes?

Comment: I think it would get fried as it would be such a high current in such a thin filament. Mind you if there were multiple filaments that might work and if the charge was high enough the ionized and heated remnants of the filament might also act as a conduit for the next strike.

Comment: Hmmm...   https://www.printedelectronicsworld.com/articles/5791/spider-silk-turned-into-electrical-wire-for-medical-devices

Comment: @puppetsockreinstateMonica oh nice, thanks for the link.